# Fixing windows that cannot start

Tags: windows-7, windows

My windows cannot start. I want to fix that by just "upgrading". That way I can keep all my program or settings.

the thing is to upgrade windows I need to start windows. So it's catch 2-2

Is there a way to upgrade windows from say command prompt or something like that?

Basically there are 2 ways to install windows. Clean install or upgrade. Well, I want to upgrade but my windows can't start. I just want to fix the windows file.

When starting up windows the windows logo shows up. After that I just got a blank screen with mouse cursor.

A lot of files got fixed by chkdsk.

But then after each reboot I just go to a blank screen. Chance is one or 2 program is problematic.

Basically I want to reinstall windows in a way that doesn't

1. require me to start windows
2. preserve all of my programs and settings including automatically unlocking my bitlocker drives

Comment: I attempted upon this quest over a year ago.  I came to the conclusion that after 2 months of research, if you cannot boot into Windows, its not possible to do an in-place upgrade.  The only installation options outside of Windows is a clean installation.  I asked this same question, was downvoted into the stone age, so I ended up deleting the question.

Comment: You can attempt an offline repair using the DISM and SFC tools but in my case I was never able to get it to work.  If you have more problems then corrupt system files then you are out of luck.  My guess part of the registry hive is also corrupt.  Of course since your system disk is encrypted booting into a WinRE and attempting those offline repairs might not even be possible.  I hope you have backups.